# TextBox bottom shadow

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have my UserСontrol, which inherits TextBox. My new TextBox transparent and I want to make the bottom of the shadow of TextBox. Сan you tell how to make it work?

For example in my Form :

```
private const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000; 
protected override CreateParams CreateParams 
{
    get
    {
        // add the drop shadow flag for automatically drawing
        // a drop shadow around the form
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
        return cp;
    } 
}
```

Comment: CS_DROPSHADOW is for form/menus (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729176(v=vs.85).aspx)). If you want shadow for TextBox frame or TextBox text, or if you want to use `ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor` (for transparency) then you have to use `ControlStyles.UserPaint` and draw everything yourself.

Comment: If you have to paint it yourself, you can only paint a shadow. You can paint a shadow right on the surface or you can have a user control made out your textbox, which paints a shadow.